# How to make the last line of a .txt file not get printed twice?

Tags: c, file, printf, scanf

I have been trying to print a list by taking the values from a .txt file. And I have been successful. But there is a problem for some reason the last line gets printed twice. I used an infinite for loop to loop through the file and used conditional statement to break from the loop if it reaches the end of file. So according to this code, my file should have stopped getting printed immediately after it reaches the end of the file. But it the for some reason the last value gets printed twice. Why is this occurring and how to solve this issue . here is the code and image of the output :

```
void readSpendMoney()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    struct spendMoney r;
    int i=1;
    char ch;
    fptr = fopen("SpendMoney.txt", "r");
    printf("\n\n\t\t***List of your spending***\n\n");
    printf("SL.      Name of item       Cost\n");
    for( ; ; )
    {
        if((ch = fgetc(fptr)) == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]s ", &r.nameItem);
            fscanf(fptr,"%f", &r.cost);

            printf("%d %15s %15.2f\n",i,r.nameItem,r.cost);
            i++;
        }

    }
    fclose(fptr);
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain how this : while ( 2 == fscanf(fptr," %[^\n] %f", r.nameItem, &r.cost)) condition works ?

Comment: @Wasi153 please *always* check the function return value from the `scanf` family.  Code that doesn't will be useless.

Comment: Note too the `%[^\n]s` is a hybrid of `%[^\n]` and `%s`.

Comment: So can this loop be written like while ( (fscanf(fptr," %[^\n]s  %f", r.nameItem, &r.cost)==2) @user3121023

Comment: Ok , I will @WeatherVane

Comment: Thanks a lot @user3121023 you solved my problem . But why error occurs if i put %[^\n]s ? what does only %[^\n] mean ? Does it mean that the code is lookin for only new lines and floats  . I am sorry I am asking a lot of questions actually I am quite new that's why. It would be really helpful if you help

Comment: Please note there is a great deal of information in the function man pages. These `scanf` type functions are quite involved, and I recommend spending an hour studying them, and trying out very small test programs to get a better feel for how it all works.